# Make A Video On Web page Not Downloadable In ReactJS

Tags: video-streaming, web-deployment

I am developing a website using ReactJS on frontend and NodeJS on backend which will display videos but it is required that videos must be not downloadable but should play online.Please suggest any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

That is not a thing. Playing a video requires it be downloaded. A file is a file. The client downloads it. The client may then play the file or save it to disk. The server can not control what the client does, and the server can’t know what the client intends to do before it does it.

The best you can do signed URLs or DRM.